What is the equation describing the shape in the following figure?
I'm currently working on making my own versions of plots from the B. Auld's book about Acoustic Fields and Waves in Solids, and one of the figures that I want to recreate contains some circle/squircle type shapes that I don't know the name of nor do I know the equation to describe them.

The shape that I mean is the shape labeled 'Quasishear,' hopefully you can help me with this.

Do you have a definition of "quasishear scattering"? How would you work it out? If you're only interested in shapes that approximate this one reasonably well, I would suggest trying polar coordinates. The curve in question looks almost identical to $r=4-\cos^2 2\theta$.

Some googling gives slowness surface and a pdf with a similar figure

This is mainly some pre research for when I start my graduation internship, so I'm also learning about the material in the meantime. But I am currently also trying to focus on preparing some basic figures that I might use in presentations/reports.

Without really knowing what these curves are, it's hard to be sure what their equations might be. But noting that they all share some rotational symmetry, it's not hard to guess that they might all have the form $r=a+b\cos^2 2\theta$ for various $a$ and $b$. The curves plotted below are
$$\color{Green}{r=4-\cos^2 2\theta},\quad\color{Blue}{r=3},\quad\color{Red}{r=1.9+\frac15\cos^2 2\theta}$$


Thank you very much, that looks great!
